# Import existing file folder to IBM Watson Application

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have downloaded on my PC this IBM Watson project:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/

and following its tutorial I've uploaded it on my IBM dashboard.
The problem is that everytime I want to change somethink in the project I've to re-upload it with the command line command `cf push`.
When I go in the Toolchain section, I can't see all the files and their folders, but only create a new repository or clone it, but in both case I haven't resolved my problem.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use:**

```
cf push APP_NAME
```

Obs.: `cf push` does not support incremental upload. It will simply push everything in the folder to the cloud. 
If your `node_modules` in the folder which resulted in a large-size upload. Try to specify what to exclude in a `.cfignore` file.

**Example** `.cfignore` **file contents:**

```
tmp/
node_modules/
my_unnecessary_file.txt
```

When executing your next `cf push` for deploying the application it will omit the files and directories listed in your `.cfignore` file.

- See more about [CF PUSH](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/getting-started.html#push).
- See more [deploy applications](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html) with CF CLI.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change anything, because when you create a toolchain it ask you to select between:
- New
- Clone
- Fork

and I tried all these options but going in the web eclipse editor files don't appear.
This s the git repository of my app:
https://git.ng.bluemix.net/consultagiovanilepolizzi/official-app2

How can I import with Git an existing project in my computer to edit it with toolchain?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you are working with the Continuous delivery, instead of uploading your app using cf push, you are going to use the toochain.

The fist step is to use the git repository, you need to create a ssh key or an access token, if you prefer to connect through https, the access token can be created in the Bluemix git, going into the [settings of your user, then Access Tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07niz.jpg)

After that, you can push your app to the repository using a git tool, the user name will be your IBM account, and the password your token.

In the delivery pipeline, the build stage checks you repository for new commits into the master, by default, and start a new build, sending to the deploy if successful.

Those links below can give you more details

[Using git Repos](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/git_working.html#git_working)

[Setting up local clients](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/git_locally.html#git_local)

[Delivery Pipeline](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/pipeline_about.html#deliverypipeline_about)